# AJAX: How would I bind autocomplete feature on KeyUp to be able to use Keyboard key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

How would I bind or use the so called "autocomplete" feature on to the code below in order to use the autocomplete features keyboard up, down and enter functionality, because currently my code doesn't have that. It is on wordpress template and it is just being controlled by mouse for right now.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search-box").keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "autocomplete.php",
            data:'keyword='+$(this).val(),        
            success: function(data){
                $("#suggesstion-box ").show();
                $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);               
            }
        });  
    }); 
});

function selectCountry(val) {
  $("#search-id").val(val);
  $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}

function updateSearchBox(el) {
  $("#search-box").val($(el).html());   
}
</script>
```

I have tried using

```
 $("#search-box").keyup.autocomplete(function() {
```

or

```
 $("#search-box").autocomplete(function() {
```

or even

```
 $("#search-box").autocomplete.keyup(function() {
```

But it doesn't pull the list. I know there is something wrong with my AJAX causing me to have this issue of keyboard is not working correctly. Any Suggestions?

Ok... I have changed my php to give out a json.

Autocomplete.php

```
<?php
include_once "functions.php";

     if(isset($_POST['keyword']))
    {
        $database = lookup_connectToDatabase();                     
        $result = pg_query($database, "SELECT country, id, state FROM customers WHERE country iLIKE '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%' OR id iLIKE '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%' ORDER BY country");

        if (!$result){
                echo "<div class='show' align='left'>No matching records.</div>";
        }else {

            while($row=pg_fetch_assoc($result)){

                $array[] = array(
                    'label' = $row['id'].': '.$row['country'].', '.$row['state'],
                    'value' = $row['id'],
                );

            } 
            echo json_encode ($array);
        }
    }                                                   
?>
```

But still doesn't seem to work right.  What am I missing with this json?

Comment: Open the console, check for the javascript errors and start by fixing them.

Comment: You also missing the dot after `$("#search-box")`. Can't invoke a method without it.

Comment: added the .keyup, but still no luck...

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to accomplish. You could set the `minLength` to `0` which would cause the autocomplete list to appear upon focus. You could set it to `1` to appear after a single letter is entered. Also why not setup the `source` portion to use your PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

In your script, this might look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search-box").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: "autocomplete.php",
        select: function(e, ui){
            $("#search-box").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#search-id").val(ui.item.value);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

See More: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

> **String:** When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query string is added with a `term` field, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results. For example, if the `source` option is set to `"http://example.com"` and the user types `foo`, a GET request would be made to `http://example.com?term=foo`. The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above.

If you must use POST, this can be done, but it's a bit more complex.

> **Function:** The third variation, a callback, provides the most flexibility and can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete.

This might look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search-box").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function(req, resp){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "autocomplete.php",
                data:'keyword=' + req.term,
                success: function(d){
                    resp(d);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function(e, ui){
            $("#search-box").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#search-id").val(ui.item.value);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

These examples are untested since you did not provide example data.

**Update**

Based on your `autocomplete.php` file, I would suggest the following:

```
<?php
include_once "functions.php";

if(isset($_POST['keyword'])){
    $database = lookup_connectToDatabase();
    $result = pg_query($database, "SELECT country, id, state FROM customers WHERE country iLIKE '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%' OR id iLIKE '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%' ORDER BY country");
    $data = array();
    if ($result){
        while($row=pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $data[] = array(
                "label" => $row['country'].', '.$row['state'],
                "value" => $row['id'],
            );
        } 
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode ($array);
}
?>
```

This should return an Array of objects with `label` and `value` properties.

> The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item. If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you provide only value properties, the `value` will also be used as the label.

If there are no matches, we'll just get an empty array in return. So let's say we get the following response:

```
[
  {
    "label": "United States, California",
    "value": 420 
  },
  {
    "label": "United States, New York",
    "value": 100 
  }
]
```

When one of these is selected, the `select` callback is executed and `#search-box` will receive the `ui.item.label`; `#search-id` will receive the `ui.item.value`.

Comment: You are close...  Still having issues but do to my fault.  In my Html the search-id  gets updated with the row id and then is sent to the server, where as the search-box just shows what the user picked out.  So I need the search-id sent to server and the user only sees the search-box ...

Comment: Then your php or result set should deliver a `label` and `value` object back as a result in json. Where label will be what they see and value is the id

Comment: So in theory, I would only need the two input fields with ids of "search-box" and "search-id".   I wouldn't need the extra div of <div class="box" id="suggesstion-box"></div> below them to show the autocomplete box, or would I?

Comment: @ShadyNicNack I updated my answer. No should not need any extra `<div>` elements.